# How to store complex data using MySQL and JSP

Tags: mysql

At present I am creating a small web application called slam book. We know slam page contains so many fields. By using MySQL tables it takes too many columns and leads to complexity for accessing the data.

Is their any solution to store the complex data by using JSP?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for storing complex data - it's called a database. You can either make your data simple and your app complex or the other way round.

Since data lasts far longer than the latest trendy presentation layer, you are far better off learning how to manipulate data properly than the other way round.

The RDBMS has proved itself over the last 30/40 years - show me a presentation layer that's done the same?

Comment: Yes,RDBMS store the information in the form of tables .What my question is ?.In my slam page nearly 20 fields are present , I can simply insert into my table so that it requires 20 columns to store the data .Finally my table became complex.                                                  Is their any possibility  to reduce the complexity of my table without creating another table in my database.

Comment: Post a diagram of your tables and the relationships between them and we'll see. Maybe you'll have to make your application more complicated - BTW, what is a "slam page"?